# Can not find property "parsingMode" nodejs jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jsdom

I want to access to the DOM of javascript file using nodejs.

```
    var fs = require('fs');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var doc   = jsdom.jsdom(fs.readFileSync("a.html"), null, {
          features: {
            FetchExternalResources   : ['script'],
            ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
            MutationEvents           : '2.0',
        }
    });

var window = doc.createWindow();
jsdom.jQueryify(window, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js", function() {
    console.log(window.a);
    console.log(window.$().jquery); //jquery version
});
```

nodejs: 5.1.2 | jsdom: 7.x | npm: 3.3.12

I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#for-the-hardcore-jsdomjsdom) shows that the signature of `jsdom.jsdom` is:

```
jsdom(markup, options);
```

You currently pass `null` for `options`, and pass your options in the 3rd parameter. Remove the `null`:

```
var doc = jsdom.jsdom(fs.readFileSync("a.html"), {
      features: {
        // ...
    }
});
```